# How to load a map with Google Map API?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-api

I had a problem when It loads the MapFragment.
In the phone's screen it does not appear nothing.

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

```
private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
protected ArrayList<GPSPoint> coord = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    //setUpMapIfNeeded();
    mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
            .getMap();
    LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
    Marker hamburg = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
            .title("Hamburg"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(HAMBURG, 15));


}
```

Answer (score 0):

mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
                mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
This is what worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try with something like that:

```
 public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

 private final LatLng STARTING_POINT=new LatLng(45.464711, 9.188736);

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   GoogleMap map=((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
   map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(STARTING_POINT, 5));
 }
}
```

To zoom the map:

```
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), 2000, null);
```

To add a pin:

```
// Default pin
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(STARTING_POINT));

// Custom pin
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(STARTING_POINT).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
```

P.S. First of all, you need to obtain an API key, enable Google Maps API in the Google Developer Console and modify the Manifest of your app setting the appropriate permissions. Yuo did it, right?